# Insert binary file into MSSQL db (varbinary) with python pymssql

Tags: sql, python-2.7, binary, pyramid, pymssql

I'm trying to insert binary data into an MSSQL database using *stored procedures* from within an pyramid web application using pymssql.

The MSSQL datatype for the respective column is `varbinary(max)`.

My question is: **What does the varbinary datatype of the MSSQL database expect me to do with the binary file before inserting it?**

Here's what I've been trying:

```
with open(tmp_file, 'rb') as content_file:
    filecontent = content_file.read()
```

... and then pass the value of `filecontent` to the stored procedure.

`tmp_file` in this case is a valid path to a `.png` file.

The MSSQL db answers with the following error:

```
*** DatabaseError: (257, 'Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not 
allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.DB-Lib error message 257, severity 16:\nGeneral
SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n')
```

I am able to insert the value of the `filecontent` variable into an SQLite (`varbinary` column) and a MySQL database (`BLOB` column) no problem.

Why is it not working with the MSSQL db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to convert the **varchar** explicitly. That's what your error message implies.

See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8f9d772a-4fa2-45b4-9fed-f03c73bd757a/implicit-conversion-from-data-type-varchar-to-varbinary-is-not-allowed-use-the-convert-function-to?forum=transactsql

This seems to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

As @Arno Rinker pointed out, there was indeed a problem with the conversion from varchar to varbinary. However, I ended up doing more than that to completely solve my problem.

I'm posting my whole solution here, just in case...

```
with open(tmp_file, 'rb') as content_file:
    filecontent = content_file.read()
    filecontent_hex = '0x'.encode('ascii') + binascii.hexlify(filecontent)

    --> post the value of filecontent_hex to a stored procedure.
```

The stored procedure receives the value of `filecontent_hex` as `varchar`, then converts it to `varbinary`.

Getting binary data out of the MSSQL-DB I then do like this:

```
fout = open(filename, "w")
filecontent_unhex = binascii.unhexlify(filecontent)
fout.write(filecontent_unhex[2:])
fout.close()
```

where `filename` and `filecontent` are in the result of the querying stored procedure.

**Conclusion:** The `binascii.hexlify()` and `binascii.unhexlify()` where not necessary for the binary interaction with SQLite and MySQL. However, these steps appeared to be required for the interaction with a MSSQL-DB.