# Insert value into VARBINARY column using sqlalchemy

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am using a MS SQL database, together with Python and sqlalchemy. One table has a column defined as

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    ...
    [address] [varbinary] (16) NULL
    ...
```

The table class `MyTable` is generated by means of table reflection. 
Assigning a string value to `MyTable.address` in my Python code triggers the exception

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) string argument without an encoding
```

when writing it to the database. Passing a `bytearray` instead yields the database error

```
(pymssql.OperationalError) (257, 
b'Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. 
Use the CONVERT function to run this query.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16 [...]
```

I understand that an encoding is required to store a string in a binary column, but how can I provide that encoding? How else could I write binary data to the database using the ORM capabilities of sqlalchemy?

For I am creating my table classes through reflection, I cannot modify the SQL code directly like described in the answer to [Insert binary file into MSSQL db (varbinary) with python pymssql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25804024/220000)

Reading the [sqlalchemy documentation on MS SQL](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html) also yielded no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that, like in my case, `address` is a large integer, one can write

```
a = 72037797995605455
MyTable.address = a.to_bytes(16, 'big')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert first the data to varbinary before saving it to the database because the data type of the address field is varbinary.

```
select convert(varbinary,[the string or data to be convert])
```

Comment: It seems I did not make clear that I want to use sqlalchemy's ORM to avoid writing SQL code. I changed my question accordingly.