# Insert byte into sql server varbinary(max) column using pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.5, pymssql

I'm attempting to insert a byte or byte array into Sql Server table using Python 3.5 and the pymssql package.  I keep getting a `pymssql.ProgrammingError` after attempting to insert.

I've used the following link and question as a reference but I'm still having trouble:

[Explicit Convert of Varbinary(max) column](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8f9d772a-4fa2-45b4-9fed-f03c73bd757a/implicit-conversion-from-data-type-varchar-to-varbinary-is-not-allowed-use-the-convert-function-to?forum=transactsql)

[Insert binary file into MSSQL db (varbinary) with python pymssql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804024/insert-binary-file-into-mssql-db-varbinary-with-python-pymssql)

I've verified I have permission and can insert other data types into the sql server database.  Below is the table structure.

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Da8oQ.png)

## Attempt 01:

```
sql_cursor = m_sql_conn.cursor()

byte_test_01 = b'This is a byte test'
hex_01 = '0x'.encode('ascii') + binascii.hexlify(byte_test_01)

string_sql_insert = "INSERT INTO CPBB_DevClusterObjs(str_cluster_id, \
    Covert(varbinary(max), obj_cluster_empty)) \
    VALUES('BatchKm|20|k-means++|1'," + hex_01 + ')'

sql_cursor.execute(string_sql_insert)
```

#### Result 01

```
pymssql.ProgrammingError

hex_01 = b'0x54686973206973206120627974652074657374'
```

## Attempt 02

```
sql_cursor = m_sql_conn.cursor()

byte_test_01 = b'This is a byte test'
hex_01 = '0x'.encode('ascii') + binascii.hexlify(byte_test_01)

list_insert_many = [('BatchKm|20|k-means++|1', hex_01)]

string_sql_insert = "INSERT INTO \
    CPBB_DevClusterObjs(str_cluster_id,Covert(varbinary(max), obj_cluster_empty)) \ 
    VALUES (%s,%b)"

sql_cursor.executemany(str_sql_statement, list_insert_many)
```

#### Result 02

```
pymssql.ProgrammingError

hex_01 = b'0x54686973206973206120627974652074657374'
```

## Attempt 03

I take out the CONVERT() function and...

```
sql_cursor = m_sql_conn.cursor()

byte_test_01 = b'This is a byte test'
hex_01 = '0x'.encode('ascii') + binascii.hexlify(byte_test_01)

string_sql_insert = "INSERT INTO CPBB_DevClusterObjs(str_cluster_id,obj_cluster_empty) \ 
     VALUES ('BatchKm|20|k-means++|1'," \ 
    + hex_01 + ')'

sql_cursor.execute(string_sql_insert)
```

#### Result 03

```
pymssql.ProgrammingError

hex_01 = b'0x54686973206973206120627974652074657374'
```

I'm missing something but I don't know what.  I definitely need some help here.

## Update 01

Below is my complete code in a test method:

```
def Test():
    # lists
    list_sql_insert_data_type = ['%s', '%b']
    list_return = list()

    # variables
    string_sql_table = r'CPBB_DevClusterObjs'
    str_sql_error = ''
    user = r'user_me'
    host = r'server_me'
    pswd = r'pswd_me'
    db_name = r'db_me'
    bool_insert_into_table = False

    # sql connection
    list_sql_conn = SqlMethods.SqlGenConnection(user, host, pswd, db_name)
    sql_cursor = list_sql_conn[1].cursor()

    # byte test variables
    byte_test_01 = b'This is a byte test'
    hex_01 = '0x'.encode('ascii') + binascii.hexlify(byte_test_01)

    # create insert string
    string_sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO ' + string_sql_table
    string_sql_insert += '(string_cluster_id, CONVERT(varbinary(max), obj_cluster_empty)) '
    string_sql_insert += "VALUES ('BatchKm|20|k-means++|1'," + "'" + str(hex_01) + "'" + ')'

    # explicit string conversation of hex_01
    string_hex_01 = "'" + str(hex_01) + "'"

    # take out the CONVERT() statement
    #string_sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO ' + string_sql_table
    #string_sql_insert += '(string_cluster_id, obj_cluster_empty) '
    #string_sql_insert += "VALUES ('BatchKm|20|k-means++|1'," + "'" + str(hex_01) + "'" + ')'

    try:
        sql_cursor.execute(string_sql_insert)
    except pymssql.OperationalError:
        str_sql_error = 'Operational error was raised'
    except pymssql.ProgrammingError:
        str_sql_error = 'A program error was raised.'
    except pymssql.Error:
        str_sql_error = 'General error raised.'
    except pymssql.DatabaseError:
        str_sql_error = 'Database error raised.'
    except pymssql.DataError:
        str_sql_error = 'Data error raised.'
    except pymssql.IntegrityError:
        str_sql_error = 'Integrity error raised.'
    except pymssql.InterfaceError:
        str_sql_error = 'Interface error raised.'
    except pymssql.InternalError:
        str_sql_error = 'Internal error raised.'
    except pymssql.NotSupportedError:
        str_sql_error = 'Not supported error raised.'
    except pymssql.StandardError:
        str_sql_error = 'Standard error raised.'
    else:
        bool_insert_into_table = True
        list_sql_conn[1].commit()
    finally:
        list_return.append(bool_insert_into_table)
        list_return.append(str_sql_error)

    # return list
    return list_return
```

#### update 01 result

I tried what you recommended initially and I received and error, "unable to implicitly convert byte to string" as a result I explicitly converted it to a string.

instead of a pymssql.ProgrammingError in getting a pymssql.OperationalError.

if I take out the CONVERT() function I get a pymssql.ProgrammingError

```
hex_01 = 0x54686973206973206120627974652074657374

string_hex_01 = "'" + str(hex_01) + "'" = 'b'0x54686973206973206120627974652074657374''

string_sql_insert = INSERT INTO CPBB_DevClusterObjs(string_cluster_id, 
                    CONVERT(varbinary(max), obj_cluster_empty)) VALUES   
                    ('BatchKm|20|k-means++','b'0x54686973206973206120627974652074657374'')
```

Should this be string_hex_01 be:

```
string_hex_01 = str(hex_01)[1:] = '0x54686973206973206120627974652074657374'
```

this also gives a pymssql.OperationalError

## Update 02

I verified that I am able to insert into the database and table.  Mental note: make sure I have my column names correct (str_cluster_id vice string_cluster_id).  I'm still getting a pymssql.OperationalError.  How does the CONVERT() function fit into this.  If I take it out I get a pymssql.ProgrammingError.

verified sql insert works:

```
# test insert into string_cluster_id
string_sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO ' + string_sql_table
string_sql_insert += ' (str_cluster_id) '
string_sql_insert += "VALUES ('BatchKm|20|k-means++|1')"
```

string_cluster_table = r'CPBB_DevClusterObjs'

## Update 03

attempted to insert the below string:

```
string_sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO CPBB_DevClusterObjs'
string_sql_insert += '(obj_cluster_empty) '
string_sql_insert += "VALUES ('0x5468697320697320612062797‌​4652074657374')"
```

#### Result update 03

```
pymssql.OperationalError
```

## Update 04

Success!!  Below is what worked.

```
string_sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO CPBB_DevClusterObjs'
string_sql_insert += '(obj_cluster_empty) '
string_sql_insert += "VALUES (CONVERT(varbinary(max), '0x5468697320697320612062797‌​4652074657374'))"
```

#### Update 04 Result

successful insert into varbinary(max) column
will post other updates as I find what else will work and what won't

## _mssql package & exception handling

In order to understand how I was able to realize where my error was I took a round about path.  I rewrote my test method using the _mssql package and took advantage of the exception handleing as directed in the documentation at _http://pymssql.org/en/stable/_mssql_examples.html.

The key for me was to realize how to use the exception handling as an object, e.g.:

```
except _mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException as db_e:
    str_sql_error = 'mssql database error raised'
exc_db_number = db_e.number
exc_db_msg = db_e.message
```

db_e.text gave me this message:

Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16: General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server.

this lead me to change where I needed the CONVERT() function to convert the data vice trying to convert the column in the destination database in which it is already a varbinary(max) column.

The insert string that worked is:

```
string_sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO CPBB_DevClusterObjs'
string_sql_insert += '(obj_cluster_empty) '
string_sql_insert += "VALUES (CONVERT(varbinary(max), '0x5468697320697320612062797‌​4652074657374'))"
```

## Lesson Learned

1. I was an 'idiot' and didn't ensure my column variables are correct. Make sure you do that before you post. It will help a lot.
2. Use the exception handling as an object.  It will help you trouble shoot where your errors are.  If you're getting back into development / coding after over a decade of absence this will help.
3. Don't be afraid to ask for help if you don't find an answer that fits what you're trying to accomplish.  I found two references but I couldn't make the connection.  Somebody will help you as evidence by this question.
4. Be as detailed and specific as possible when asking for help.  I could've done better at posting my exact test code originally.  It probably wouldn't speed up the process.

## Final Version of Test Code

Below is the final version of the test method that works to insert a binary piece of data into a varbinary(max) column in Microsoft Sql Server.

```
def Test_01():

    # lists
    list_sql_insert_data_type = ['%s', '%b']
    list_return = list()

    # variables
    string_sql_table = r'CPBB_DevClusterObjs'
    str_sql_error = ''
    user = r'user_me'
    host = r'server_me'
    pswd = r'pswd_me'
    db_name = r'db_me'
    bool_insert_into_table = False

    # sql connection
    list_sql_conn = SqlMethods.SqlGenConnection(user, host, pswd, db_name)
    sql_cursor = list_sql_conn[1].cursor()

    # _mssql connection
    _mssql_conn = _mssql.connect(server = host, user = user, password = pswd, database = db_name)

    # byte test variables
    byte_test_01 = b'This is a byte test'
    hex_01 = '0x'.encode('ascii') + binascii.hexlify(byte_test_01)

    # explicit string conversion of hex_01
    string_hex_01 = "'" + str(hex_01) + "'"
    string_hex_02 = str(hex_01)[1:]

    # create insert string
    #string_sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO CPBB_DevClusterObjs'
    #string_sql_insert += '(str_cluster_id, obj_cluster_empty) '
    #string_sql_insert += "VALUES ('BatchKm|20|k-means++|1','0x5468697320697320612062797‌​4652074657374')"

    # sucess!!  below insert works
    string_sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO CPBB_DevClusterObjs'
    string_sql_insert += '(obj_cluster_empty) '
    string_sql_insert += "VALUES (CONVERT(varbinary(max), '0x5468697320697320612062797‌​4652074657374'))"

    # test insert into string_cluster_id
    #string_sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO ' + string_sql_table
    #string_sql_insert += ' (str_cluster_id) '
    #string_sql_insert += "VALUES ('BatchKm|20|k-means++|1')"

    # take out the CONVERT() statement
    #string_sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO ' + string_sql_table
    #string_sql_insert += '(str_cluster_id, obj_cluster_empty) '
    #string_sql_insert += "VALUES ('BatchKm|20|k-means++|1'," + "'" + str(hex_01) + "'" + ')'

    try:
        sql_cursor.execute(string_sql_insert)
    except pymssql.OperationalError as oe:
        str_sql_error = 'Operational error was raised'
    except pymssql.ProgrammingError:
        str_sql_error = 'A program error was raised.'
    except pymssql.Error:
        str_sql_error = 'General error raised.'
    except pymssql.DatabaseError:
        str_sql_error = 'Database error raised.'
    except pymssql.DataError:
        str_sql_error = 'Data error raised.'
    except pymssql.IntegrityError:
        str_sql_error = 'Integrity error raised.'
    except pymssql.InterfaceError:
        str_sql_error = 'Interface error raised.'
    except pymssql.InternalError:
        str_sql_error = 'Internal error raised.'
    except pymssql.NotSupportedError:
        str_sql_error = 'Not supported error raised.'
    except pymssql.StandardError:
        str_sql_error = 'Standard error raised.'
    else:
        bool_insert_into_table = True
        list_sql_conn[1].commit()
    finally:
        list_return.append(bool_insert_into_table)
        list_return.append(str_sql_error)

    # return list
    return list_return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify your string_sql_insert to:

```
string_sql_insert = "INSERT INTO CPBB_DevClusterObjs(str_cluster_id, \
CONVERT(varbinary(max), obj_cluster_empty)) \
VALUES('BatchKm|20|k-means++|1'," + "'" + hex_01 + "'"')'
```

You are inserting this:

```
INSERT INTO CPBB_DevClusterObjs(str_cluster_id, obj_cluster_empty)     VALUES('BatchKm|20|k-means++|1',0x54686973206973206120627974652074657374)
```

Instead of this:

```
INSERT INTO CPBB_DevClusterObjs(str_cluster_id, obj_cluster_empty)     VALUES('BatchKm|20|k-means++|1','0x54686973206973206120627974652074657374')
```

If you look at VALUES you will see why it is throwing an error.

According to https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/pull/179/files

```
def insert_and_select(self, cname, value, vartype, params_as_dict=False):
```

vartype is 's'

```
def test_binary_string(self):
    bindata = '{z\n\x03\x07\x194;\x034lE4ISo'.encode('ascii')
    testval = '0x'.encode('ascii') + binascii.hexlify(bindata)
    colval = self.insert_and_select('data_binary', testval, 's')
    self.typeeq(bindata, colval)
    eq_(bindata, colval)
```

Comment: Ok well we are one step closer.  OperationalError is cased by db side. http://pymssql.org/en/latest/ref/pymssql.html.  Can you make sure you are connected to db? and check if the your table CPBB_DevClusterObjs exists.

Comment: I verified that I have access and inserted a value into the first column; mental note make sure I have my column names correct (str_cluster_id vice string_cluster_id);  still getting a pymssql.OperationalError; how does the CONVERT() function fit into this?  If I take it out I get a pymssql.ProgrammingError but with it in I get a pymssql.OperationalError.  See update 02.

Comment: can you try this: see what you get. INSERT INTO CPBB_DevClusterObjs(str_cluster_id,obj_cluster_empty) VALUES('BatchKm|20|k-means++|1','0x54686973206973206120627974652074657374')

Comment: I tried the string: INSERT INTO CPBB_DevClusterObjs(str_cluster_id,obj_cluster_empty) VALUES('BatchKm|20|k-means++|1','0x5468697320697320612062797‌​4652074657374') and an pymssql.OperatoinalError occurred.  I have double checked the permissions and have inserted multiple strings into the first column.  It seems the database is not  recognizing '0x5468697320697320612062797‌​4652074657374' as data that will fit into a varbinary(max) column.  Can you set-up a quick db and replicate this error?

Comment: obj_cluster_empty does it expect string or byte?  How did you create that table?

Comment: Also what version is the pymssql?  You saw that it was reported as a bug, then it was fixed.  Make sure you have the correct updated version.

Comment: Can you add this to exceptions:  except pymssql.OperationalError as e: print e . So we can see more verbose error stacktrace

Comment: I found the issue.  I had the CONVERT() function in the wrong place.  I used the _mssql package error functions to find there was a syntax error near the original CONVERT() function.  see update 04.  thank you for the help.  I really appreciate it.  I will post the error messages tomorrow so all can see my mistake and use it to their advantage.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert_sql = "INSERT INTO [collecttest].[dbo].[Table_1]([c1],[c2]) VALUES (%s, %s)"
with open("../data/tpc-ds_ER.png", 'rb') as f:
    bdata = f.read()
    # hdata = f.read().encode('hex')  # only python2
    # hdata = f.read()
#     hdata = binascii.hexlify(bdata) # 
    print(type(bdata))
    values = [
        (pymssql.Binary(bdata), pymssql.Binary(bdata)),
        (pymssql.Binary(bdata), pymssql.Binary(bdata)),
    ]

    cursor.executemany(insert_sql, values)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for why this is the answer. Answers that are little more than just the code are probably going to be deleted.