# Decoding array of numbers from database in python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, binary, decode

I read the  variable x from a column in a database using SQLAlchemy. I know that this string represents 60 (float or float16) numbers.  I had no luck in using np.fromstring. I wonder how to cast this to a list of numbers in SQLAlchemy.

The following page is to insert a byte to specific column in pymssql.
[Insert byte into sql server varbinary(max) column using pymssql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637062/insert-byte-into-sql-server-varbinarymax-column-using-pymssql)

```
import numpy as np
import binascii
x=b'\x91\xfe\xc3\xfe\xeb\xfe\xef\xfe\x04\xff\x1d\xff+\xff+\xff1\xff:\xffD\xffO\xffS\xffc\xffl\xff|\xff\x8f\xff\xa8\xff\xb3\xff\xbd\xff\xc7\xff\xcc\xff\xd0\xff\xd6\xff\xe5\xff\xfe\xff\xfe\xff\xfe\xff\xfe\xff\xfe\xff\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' 
y = np.fromstring(x,dtype=np.float16,count=60)
print(y)


[             nan              nan              nan              nan
              nan              nan              nan              nan
              nan              nan              nan              nan
              nan              nan              nan              nan
              nan              nan              nan              nan
              nan              nan              nan              nan
              nan              nan              nan              nan
              nan              nan   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07
   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07
   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07
   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07
   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07
   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07
   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07
   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07   3.57627869e-07]
```

I am expecting a number between -40 to 40 for each array element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out the numbers are saved in int16 format. Also, np.fromstring is deprecated, and replaced by np.frombuffer. The unit was in mm instead of cm, so the resultant numbers are between -400 to 400.

```
import numpy as np
import binascii
x=b'\x91\xfe\xc3\xfe\xeb\xfe\xef\xfe\x04\xff\x1d\xff+\xff+\xff1\xff:\xffD\xffO\xffS\xffc\xffl\xff|\xff\x8f\xff\xa8\xff\xb3\xff\xbd\xff\xc7\xff\xcc\xff\xd0\xff\xd6\xff\xe5\xff\xfe\xff\xfe\xff\xfe\xff\xfe\xff\xfe\xff\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' 
y = np.fromstring(x,dtype=np.float16,count=60)
print(y) 

[-367 -317 -277 -273 -252 -227 -213 -213 -207 -198 -188 -177 -173 -157
 -148 -132 -113  -88  -77  -67  -57  -52  -48  -42  -27   -2   -2   -2
   -2   -2    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6
    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6
    6    6    6    6]
```